Is it possible to completely disable fullwidth English character on keyboard input on macOS?
Is it possible to completely disable fullwidth English character on keyboard input on macOS?
Never have I need fullwidth English in any circumstance. I'm using "Zhuyin - Traditional" keyboard input and it will accidentally types “ｆｕｌｌｗｉｄｔｈ” English when switching to "Zhuyin" keyboard too quickly, and I have to manually switch back and force to make me type in Chinese like it should be.
Is there any way to completely disable the behaviour? or anyone knows why this is happening? (I still have no idea how sometimes it switches to fullwidth English instead of actually makes me type in Chinese, am I missing something?)
